# Why focus does not work properly in profile-dropdown?

Tags: html, css

I wrote the following dropdown menu feature:

```css
.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown:focus .profile-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown .profile-dropdown-content {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: -.1rem;
  top: 0.4rem;
  border-radius: 0.05rem;
  padding: 0.15rem 0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="uc-main-container flex-column">
  <div class="uc-main-top flex">
    <ul class="uc-cp flex">
      <li class="uc-cp-item">home</li>
      <li class="uc-cp-item profile-dropdown" tabidex="-1">
        <a class="user-icon">menu</a>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-content" tabindex="-1">
          <a href="/profile" class="profile-menu-profile">Profile</a>
          <a href="/settings" class="profile-menu-settings">Settings</a>
          <a href="/logout" class="profile-menu-logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**

Clicking on *menu* should display *profile-dropdown-content*

**Actual Result:**

Clicking *menu* does nothing.

Comment: I STRONGLY suggest you don't have submenus unless you have a very large number of links, even then I think they're fairly inaccessible to many people

Comment: @ZachJensz My need here is to have to use it, but thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The following selector will achieve what you want:**

`.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown a:focus + .profile-dropdown-content`

**The changes I made to get it to work:**

Your selector:
`.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown:focus .profile-dropdown-content`

1. `.profile-dropdown` is on the `<li>` element, which is not being focused, you need to check for focus on the actual `<a>` itself.
2. `.profile-dropdown-content` isn't a child of the rest of our selector now, so we use the adjacent sibling selector `+` to select the next sibling that we want to style.
3. Your anchor element needs an `href` attribute in order to be focusable

Here is a working snippet:

```css
.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown a:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown a:focus + .profile-dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.uc-main-container .uc-main-top .profile-dropdown .profile-dropdown-content {
  transition: all 300ms ease;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  right: -.1rem;
  top: 0.4rem;
  border-radius: 0.05rem;
  padding: 0.15rem 0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="uc-main-container flex-column">
  <div class="uc-main-top flex">
    <ul class="uc-cp flex">
      <li class="uc-cp-item">home</li>
      <li class="uc-cp-item profile-dropdown" tabidex="-1">
        <a class="user-icon" href="#">menu</a>
        <div class="profile-dropdown-content" tabindex="-1">
          <a href="/profile" class="profile-menu-profile">Profile</a>
          <a href="/settings" class="profile-menu-settings">Settings</a>
          <a href="/logout" class="profile-menu-logout">Logout</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```